# i have 2 sound in 2 different files , and i want to play a sound if the first sound end

Tags: java, swing, audio, jbutton, javasound

I have two sounds and I want to play the first song after I press the button and after the sound ends to play the second sound.

So I want to use if statement if the first sound end play the second sound.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class my_Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton button;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;
    JButton button4;
    JLabel label;
    Clip clip;
    Clip clip2;
    my_Frame() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        File file = new File("src/GUI/Buttons/Quiz/music.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
       clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);

        File file2 = new File("src/GUI/Buttons/Quiz/READYSETGO_Trim.wav");
      AudioInputStream  audioInputStream2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file2);
        clip2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip2.open(audioInputStream2);

        ImageIcon answer_label= new ImageIcon("src/GUI/Buttons/Quiz/Answer_Laber.png");
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("src/GUI/Buttons/Quiz/Text_Label.png");

        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(25, 50, 700, 200);

        label.setText("<html>This is the ultimate quiz <br>do you want try it ?</html>");
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 25));

        label.setIcon(imageIcon);

        button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setText("yes");
        button.setBounds(200, 300, 100, 100);
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.setIcon(answer_label);

        button2 = new JButton();
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button2.setText("no");
        button2.setBounds(350, 300, 100, 100);
        button2.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        button2.setFocusable(false);
        button2.setVisible(true);
        button2.setIcon(answer_label);

        button3 = new JButton();
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        button3.setText("2");
        button3.setBounds(200, 300, 100, 100);
        button3.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        button3.setFocusable(false);
        button3.setIcon(answer_label);

        button4 = new JButton();
        button4.addActionListener(this);
        button4.setText("4");
        button4.setBounds(350, 300, 100, 100);
        button4.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);

        button4.setFocusable(false);
        button4.setIcon(answer_label);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(760, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocation(790, 0);
        this.add(button);
        this.add(button2);
        this.add(label);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        this.setLayout(null);
    }
```

This is the button function. I want if I press the button the `clip2` starts and after it ends the first clip starts.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "niiiiiiiiiice");
        clip2.start();

        getContentPane().removeAll();
        repaint();

        label.setText("What is 1+1");

            this.add(button3);
            this.add(button4);
            this.add(label);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==button2){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) ..

Comment: .. along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) `getContentPane().removeAll();` Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 1):

`Clip` implements `Line`, so you can use a [LineListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/LineListener.html) in order to get a notification when the `Clip` ends (LineEvent.Type = STOP).

The class which implements the listening can be set to trigger the next thing you want to happen when it receives the notification.